# Does anyone know how to successfully integrate Seam and Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, seam

As the title says. Is there a way to integrate the two?

Comment: I don't think what I'm asking is possible. So I'm closing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure it's possible if you're skilled with both, but the question on my lips and all the Seam developers is "why?"

Seam combines JSF and Hibernate.  Where does Spring fit?  What is it providing for you that the Seam stack doesn't?

I haven't done it.  I use Spring and Hibernate but not Seam.  As far as I know, it's a JBOSS-only solution.

You can certainly use Spring, Hibernate, and JSF together.  You just can't use any Seam-specific code.  If you choose to go that way, you can deploy your code on any Java EE app server, including JBOSS.

Comment: It can be run with other JPA providers and on other appservers but it is a JBoss-grown technology.  It's also end-to-end so I too am confused as to why you'd combine it with Spring MVC.

Comment: I wasn't asking about Spring in general. Spring and Seam are easy together for things like Spring managed transactions for example. The question is about Spring MVC in particular.I don't like JSFs component based MVC and prefer Spring MVC for its template based approach.You didn't answer my question

Comment: Actually, I think I did.  I said I didn't have personal experience with integrating Spring into Seam.  If it's JSF you don't like, then toss out Seam and just use Spring, with its MVC, and Hibernate.  I don't see Spring and Seam together, especially given that last bit of info from you.

Answer (score 0):

The point of Seam is that it is a closed(-ish) technology stack combining JSF and Hibernate.  I say "closed" because it started that way but isn't strictly true anymore.  For example, you can run it on appserver that aren't JBoss and use different JPA providers.  That being said, it is primarily used on JBoss+JSF+Hibernate.

As for how to integrate it with Spring MVC, well that doesn't make a lot of sense.  Why not then just use Spring MVC + Hibernate + JSF if you really want (I"m not a big fan of JSF but to each his own).